# Resultset.next returns true but doesn't return the value

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I am trying to read from a mysql table and I am doing the following:

```
protected void pushRegisteredStudentsData() {
    try {
        conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        String userID = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(userID);
        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("ID");
            this.studentID = id;
            String insertSql = "INSERT INTO REGISTEREDSTUDENTS(StudentID, ModuleCode) VALUES ('" + studentID + "', + '"
                    + this.moduleCode + "')";
            System.out.println("Inserting into REGISTEREDSTUDENTS.. [" + id + "]" + "[" + this.moduleCode + "]");
            stmt.executeUpdate(insertSql);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {

    }
}
```

..but for some reason,

```
while (rs.next()) {
    int id = rs.getInt("ID");
```

always returns **the same ID**, even though the table **has different** ID's on every line!

Does anyone have an idea why that might be?
Thank you in advance! :(

**EDIT:**
I was using a single statement to execute 2 updates, which was causing the problem!

Comment: Please paste your code directly. Did you try `int id = Integer.parseInt(rs.getObject(1))`

Comment: Is the ID column unique, meaning is it possible to have multiple rows in Student table with same ID?

Comment: No, as I thought I didn't want to get the object by absolute value, but go line by line and read in stead.. @YassinHajaj

Comment: @DBug the ID is unique!

Comment: Which column is your ID column? If it is the first, the code I provided you should work for every line.

Comment: It is the first column! But even after I tried getting the second column, named StudentName(with the same code but just rs.getInt("StudentName") it would still return the same name for all the lines that are inside the mysql table!
And your code didn't do the job either! @YassinHajaj

Comment: Did you fill the catch section of your try on your system?

Comment: @CostisAivalis I just did and the result is:

java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

even thought I never close it..hmm

Comment: You can not insert with stmt = conn.createStatement(); You need a ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bit weird that it returns always the same value because it should only return the first value ONCE.

If you print the stacktrace instead of just catching the exception and doing nothing, you will see that it will print something like:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:794)
```

You are using THE SAME statement for a Select and then for an Insert. This causes the resultSet that is "attached" to the Statement to close because it is not supposed to be used again.

It can be easily fixed by creating another statement:

```
        String insertSql = "INSERT INTO REGISTEREDSTUDENTS(StudentID, ModuleCode) VALUES ('" + studentID + "', + '"
                + this.moduleCode + "')";
        System.out.println("Inserting into REGISTEREDSTUDENTS.. [" + id + "]" + "[" + this.moduleCode + "]");
        Statement stmt2 = conn.createStatement();
        stmt2.executeUpdate(insertSql);
```

Comment: You sir are a Legend! If I could, I would give you not 1 but 2 up points! Thank you! @luanjot